# Help Defining a Monoid

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, definition, monoid

$$
\text{Let}\space 
A:=
\left\{\space x^p+y^p=z^p\in\mathbb{N}^*
\space\space\middle|\space\space
\begin{array}{ll}
x,y,z,p\in\mathbb{N}^*\space\text{such that p is prime and} \\
\forall x_0,y_0,z_0\in\mathbb{N}^*\space\text{such that}\space x_0^p+y_0^p=z_0^p\in\mathbb{N}^*, \\
\text{if}\space x_0y_0z_0\ne xyz\space\text{then}\space xyz<x_0y_0z_0 
\end{array}
\space
\right
\}. \\
$$

$A\subset\mathbb{N}^*.$

$$\forall a,b,c\in (A\cup\{0\})\space\text{and}\space d,g,h\in(\mathbb{N}^*\cup\{0\})\space\text{let}\space(a,d),(b,g),(c,h)\in (A\cup\{0\})\times(\mathbb{N}^*\cup\{0\})=:B\space\text{and define}+\text{by}\\(a,d)+((b,g)+(c,h)):=(0,a+d+b+g+c+h)
:=(a+b+c, d+g+h):=((a,d)+(b,g))+(c,h)\in B.$$

$e:=(0,0)\in B.\\$

$\text{If}\space (k,l)\in B,(k,l)+e=(0,k+l)+e=(0,k+l)=e+(0,k+l) =(k,l)\in B.$

$\therefore\space(B,+,e)\space\text{is a commutative monoid and}\space(B,+,e)\cong\space(\mathbb{N},+,0)$.

Is what I've done correct? I have an idea but it relies on me defining a monoid this way. I am not a professional and would appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: If $\Bbb{N}^*$ means the positive natural numbers, then $A = \{2\}$ because the condition $x_0^p + y_0^p \in \Bbb{N}^*$ is trivially true, so $x$ and $y$ can just be taken to be $1$.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to edit it.

Comment: This would be a bit more readable with less symbols and more words. Anyway, your definition of $+$ is no good: you're essentially just saying "define $+$ in a way such that it is associative" , but what you should be doing is defining $+$ by defining it for any two elements $(a, d), (b, g)$, and then showing that what you defined is indeed associative (and has the identity you gave).

Comment: Made a second edit. How is it no good to just say that I define the binary operation + in that way?

Comment: Besides that, you need to show that the defined of two elements is still indeed contained in $B$, since this is kind of non-trivial here. Essentially, the checklist for a monoid is the following: Choose a set $M$ and an operation $M \times M \rightarrow M$, and then show that that operation does indeed satisfy closure (i.e. show that it is actually $M \times M \rightarrow M$ and not just some arbitrary function between sets), is associative, and has an identity element.

Comment: @matt Because it is not clear what monoid structure you are defining on this set. From your definition, I am not sure what $(a, d) + (b,g)$ would equal

Comment: @tolUnne thanks, I’m going to work on this and will try to get to a good definition.